# Create a new object in Angular 11 app based on values in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I am having an Angular 11 app in which I have an array of objects as shown below.

```
details = [
      {
        "name": "firstName",
        "content": "Tom"
      },
      {
        "name": "lastName",
        "content": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "name": "email",
        "content": "tomsmith@test.com"
      }
]
```

I want to create an object from above array as shown below.

```
output = {
   firstName: {value: "Tom"},
   lastName: {value: "Smith"},
   email: {value: "tomsmith@test.com"}
}
```

For simplicity I have only shown 3 objects in the **details** array but there can be any number of them. So I want the conversion to happen irrespective of the number of objects in the **details** array. How can I create the above **output** object? Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm against to the other answers proposed. As an alternative you can also do it with the help of a **"for-of"** loop and applying **destructured assignment**.

```js
const details = [ { "name": "firstName", "content": "Tom" }, { "name": "lastName", "content": "Smith" }, { "name": "email", "content": "tomsmith@test.com" } ];
let result = {}
for ({ name: n, content: value } of details) { result[n] = { value: value }; }
console.log(result)
```

[MDN Reference - Deconstructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#For_of_iteration_and_destructuring)

Answer (score 3):

you could do with [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const details = [ { "name": "firstName", "content": "Tom" }, { "name": "lastName", "content": "Smith" }, { "name": "email", "content": "tomsmith@test.com" } ];

const res = details.reduce(
    (acc, {name, content: value}) => (acc[name] = {value}, acc), {}
);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I am using the above code in Angular 11 app. I am getting errors
1) Parameter 'acc' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2) Binding element 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type.
3) Binding element 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: sorry i don't know angular and type. please updated your question with `angular` tag. for ref please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087489/typescript-and-array-reduce-function

Answer (score 2):

Map the array to an array of `[name, { value }]` pairs, and convert to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`.

With Typescript you'll need to set the target as ES2019 at least in your TS config, and it doesn't require any type definition ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUygQwJYBsIwLwwNoDeARGMgLYJEBcRAZqgE7QBy5lANEaGFAj9UQAqIMkQC%207YqQoD0yFmyKduvfjQDKZVFAAW4ySUU0EZNOiVdwqqAKgiIW3QAFe0AHShRYgLoAoX9zQMAwIEACu6LC4APIARgBWCMBQbrQMIgCiPAyooQAUvjDwSGYQbqYADnl5BDDSCOwwKnxQVDAAbsjoYQgwYgCUOAB8%20PWNtZ3dvT79vrMB4BAg6Ahu6CAA5nkh4ZH9QA)).

```js
const details = [{"name":"firstName","content":"Tom"},{"name":"lastName","content":"Smith"},{"name":"email","content":"tomsmith@test.com"}]

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  details.map(({ name, content: value }) => [name, { value }])
)

console.log(result)
```