# Angular Observable reduce function error "Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'."

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reduce

I have a code in which the `memberships$` is an observable of objects that have a property "role". I want to use `reduce` function in order to traverse all of them, and if anyone's role is "Collector" I want to return value `true`. This is the code:

```
hasCollectorRole$: Observable<boolean> = this.memberships$.pipe(
    map(arr => {
      return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
        if (val.role == "Collector") {
          acc = true;
        }
        return acc;
      }, false)
    })
  );
```

This is the error that I get on it:

```
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [specifying the reducer's default value's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087489/typescript-and-array-reduce-function/47474775#47474775) via:

```js
arr.reduce(..., false as boolean)
```

Right now, it looks like TS thinks the type that should be returned is `false`, not `boolean`, and `true` is not assignable to type `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `.some()` instead of `.reduce()` if you want to traverse a list and see if any role equals `"Collector"`

```
hasCollectorRole$: Observable<boolean> = this.memberships$.pipe(
  map(arr => {
    return arr.some((val) => val.role === "Collector")
  })
);
```

```js
const testCollector = ['test', 'Collector'];
const testNoCollector = ['test', 'NotCollector'];

console.log('result with Collector', testCollector.some(t => t === 'Collector'));
console.log('result Without Collector', testNoCollector.some(t => t === 'Collector'));
```